# Custom listener/interface doesn't works in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, abstract-class

I'm new on build a custom interface class.
In my app, I would to build a custom listener to call a particular method in my `MainActivity`.
When I execute the code, I receive an error...this is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.robertot.timereport.inteface.CustomInterface.onUpdateListJob()' on a null object reference
    at com.robertot.timereport.pages.MyFragment$3.onClick(NewJobFragment.java:217)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
```

This is my code:

CustomInterface.java

```
public interface CustomInterface {
    public void onUpdateListJob();
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private CustomInterface listener;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        listener.onUpdateListJob();    // CRASH HERE (Line 217)
        //...
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CustomInterface {
    //...

    @Override
    public void onUpdateListJob() {
        // do works...
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listener` is never initialized. I imagine you attach the `Fragment` to your `Activity` somewhat like the code below:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
MyFragment mFragment = new MyFragment();
transaction.add(R.id.container, mFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

In `MyFragment` there is a method you can override:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) { 
    this.listener = (CustomInterface) activity; 
}
```

`onAttach` is called when, you guessed it, the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`. But you can also do it with a setter, or set the `listener` in the constructor.

Comment: ok!! Thanks man!! I'm trying but I receive this exception on onAttach method: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robertot.timereport.pages.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.robertot.timereport.interfaces.CustomInterface

Comment: Edit: I've fixed the issue...but in MainActivity (implements CustomInterface) doesn't calling the method onUpdateListJob()...

Comment: Hey, What to do in case of `ClassCastException`?. I am facing the same issue. How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

`listener` has never been assigned. I don't see `listener = [something]` anywhere.

Comment: Yeah! You're right! I never assigned listener...
But, sorry for my nescience: How can I initialize? Can you write a simple code, please?

Comment: `onAttach(Activity activity){ listener = (CustomInterface) activity; }`